# How do you reset an EditText background to default after setting it to transparent?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So, I have an EditText where I disable it and set the background to transparent when the user presses the enter key.  I also have a reset button, and when that button is pressed, I want to set the EditText back to it's default formatting.  The default formatting has the hint enabled, no background, and just an underline.  (I don't have enough rep to post what the beginning formatting looks like...)

No matter what I try, I can't get it to go back to that formatting.

I've tried

```
teamA.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
```

but that formatting is definitely not what the default formatting is.

I can't set the formatting to a drawable variable and call it later, as I'm saving variables to a bundle in onSaveInstanceState to maintain them if the screen orientation changes, and it seems like you can't save a drawable to a bundle.

This is where I'm changing the formatting on the EditText:

```
public TextView.OnEditorActionListener editorListenerA = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            EditText teamA = findViewById(R.id.team_a);
            teamA.setEnabled(false);
            teamA.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            teamA.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            teamAText = teamA.getText().toString();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

And this is where I'm trying to reset it:

```
public void resetNames(View view) {
    EditText teamA = findViewById(R.id.team_a);
    teamA.setEnabled(true);
    teamA.setBackgroundResource(????????);
    teamA.setText("");
    teamA.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
    teamA.setHint(getString(R.string.team_a_name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your old background and then reuse it, just like that:

```
Drawable teamABg = teamA.getBackground();
```

and then set again:

```
teamA.setBackgroundDrawable(teamABg);
```

Comment: Won't teamABg be destroyed on screen rotate?  Or are drawables preserved through that?

Comment: no, they are not, but you can always pass as `Bundle savedInstanceState`, but perhaps would be better for you to check the drawable and verify if you can replicate.